# Excel if statement: if a cell is blank then leave this one blank, if it is a number, fill with number from another cell

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

Hi I could use some help. I'm creating a billing invoice.

besides date and description, I have the following columns: "Quantity", "Unit Price", "Total". "Unit Price" is referenced from a cell on another page in the same workbook.

I want to have it as follows:
  If "Quantity" is blank, then leave "Unit Price" blank. If "Quantity" has a number in it than fill "Unit Price" with the amount from the cell on another page in same worksheet.

Thanks all.

Answer (score 2):

Without any data shown:
If your quantity value is in cell A4,

Then, assuming B4 will contain unit price put the formula

```
=IF(A4="","",Unit price)
```

Unit price will be the cell containing the price,

However, you could use a vlookup there to collect the price according to the product...